# Search in column value table structure

Tags: php, mysql

I got a table structure looking like this:

```
table_items
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Hello |
+----+-------+

table_values
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | items_id |   columnname |        value        |
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 |  description | This is the desc... |
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 |        hobby | My hobby is comp... |
+----+----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

I wan't to search in each of the value fields for the Hello item and all other items on the site. What's the best way of doing that?

Comment: You have a _value_ and you search for the corresponding _column_. Is that?

Comment: what is your wished result from the above tables ?

Comment: 1 hour and no feedback from OP? Do you want a correct solution?

Comment: I tried to do it with a left join but it resulted in an endless query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem and it was to use indexes and of course left join the tables. Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the 2 tables, linking the `items_id` in the `table_values` with the `id` in the `table_items` table (which has the title `Hello`)

```
SELECT table_values.*
FROM table_items, table_values
WHERE table_items.title='Hello'
AND table_items.id=table_values.items_id
```

I've assumed you only need the `table_value` information (as we know the table_items.title is Hello, and table_items.id will be the same as table_values.items_id)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this SQL SELECT command:

```
SELECT table_items.title, table_values.columnname, table_values.value FROM table_items
INNER JOIN table_values ON table_items.id = table_values.items_id
WHERE table_items.title LIKE '%Hello%'
UNION
SELECT table_items.title, table_values.columnname, table_values.value FROM table_items
INNER JOIN table_values ON table_items.id = table_values.items_id
WHERE table_values.columnname LIKE '%Hello%' || table_values.value LIKE '%Hello%';
```

and SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11539/4

Answer (score -1):

Use an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT table_values.*
FROM table_values
INNER JOIN table_items
ON table_items.title LIKE CONCAT(table_values.value, '%')
```

Comment: `table_values.items_id` refers to items table?? where does Hello come into this? It doesn't appear in `table_values.value` example data

Comment: It says that he not only needs it for "Hello", but for all other values. Maybe I read the question wrong. But, I interpreted it as he was saying that he wanted to link the two tables on a possible match between the table_items.title and the table_values.value match (not just one).

Comment: I read it as `each of the value fields`  (value column in table_values) `for the hello item` (item_id=1, ie Hello id in items table - otherwise why have 2 tables?). Without OP feedback we are both stabbing in the dark

Comment: Agreed. His question is worded very vaguely.